# Flex keyboard Event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

I jus want to know, In Flex Datagrid If the pressed key is Enter, stop the propagation and dispatch a fake Tab Event.

Any suggesstion,
Thankxx

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER){
    event.stopPropagation();
    yourTarget.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, true, false, 0, 9));
}
```